# Xsd2Code Plugin in VS2015

Tags: c#, xsd, visual-studio-2015, xsd2code

I have downloaded and installed Xsd2Code plugin.

But in the visual studio, when i right click on the xsd file, i am not able to see the option "Run Xsd2Code generation".

I am struggling with this.

Please help me guys.

Comment: Got the same issue. Downloaded installer from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56ec19b6-8c47-4d00-b1b3-45f570411447 and after instalation I can't see it anywhere in Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise).

Answer (score 2):

They have just renamed the product to xsd2code++:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56ec19b6-8c47-4d00-b1b3-45f570411447

Answer (score 1):

There is (meanwhile?) a hint on the download page that this version doesn't support Visual Studio 2015:

"NOTE : xsd2code community edition 3.4 do not support Vs 2015"

https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/releases/view/121223

Answer (score 0):

Project xsd2code.codeplex.com is not updated frequently, you can see that newest item in download section is from November 2013.

If you want to use it with VS2015 you have these options:

1. use the updated paid version from www.xsd2code.com
2. get sources, compile them, and somehow create package for VS2015

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For me **reinstall** helped. I downloaded `xsd2code.exe` from [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56ec19b6-8c47-4d00-b1b3-45f570411447)

Another option for you might be, after you install the tool, go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Xsd2Code` and run the `Xsd2Code.vsPackage.vsix` by hand. It either installs the extension or informs you it is already there.

Comment: This requires a licence - not really a solution.